# Setting variable value inside an element

Tags: asp.net

I usually do the language variation by using code such as

```
<%= StrEnterName %>
```

and declaring/populating it by a public field in the code behind. Now, I though I'd use a placeholder, meaning the variable string should go into a tag but it then is assumed to be a literal and instead of the translation i do see all the percentage signs and brackets. So, the following is apparently wrong.

```
<input id="Name" placeholder="<%= StrEnterName %>" runat="server"></input>
```

What is the correct syntax for that?

Comment: @chridam It's a `type="text"`. I didn't use it explicitly since it's the default. Do you mean that the syntax **is** correct but doesn't work for certain types of `input`?!

Comment: Have a look at the W3C spec on the content attribute 'placeholder' http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-input-element.html as well as http://weblogs.asp.net/dotnetstories/archive/2011/12/24/using-html-5-form-input-elements-in-asp-net-applications.aspx. Perhaps as an ASP.NET Webforms alternative to use the html5 placeholder to input textbox in ASP.NET, you can add attribute placeholder to asp:Textbox tag and then specify in code behind like what @AbeMiessler did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is a server side control why not just set it from code behind?

```
//In page load
Name.placeholder = StrEnterName;
```

UPDATE:

You can specify any attribute you want this way:

```
Name.Attributes["placeholder"] = StrEnterName;
```

Comment: Input has no `placeholder` property.

Comment: Besides what @TimSchmelter said, I'd like to know in general how to solve this, should I at some point be requested by a crazy/drunk client to generate parts of the markup dynamically. (Not probable but possible...)

Comment: @tim-schmelter HTML5 provides new input types with the placeholder attribute http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh547102.aspx

Comment: @chridam: Yes, but [`HtmlInputText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlinputtext_properties%28v=vs.110%29) has no `Placeholder` property and this is what a `input type="text runt="server" id="Name"` is on severside. The updated answer should work(+1).